# Extract Part of URL and Navigate to it

Tags: html, url

I have no idea how to do this, but I need something that will take the last part of a url and navigate to it. (probably more effective to take out first part) For example

```
http://WEBSITE.com/mailto:exampledesk@googlegroups.com?subject=Help Needed%3A%20{{case.id}}{{case.subject}}
```

Would navigate to:

```
mailto:exampledesk@googlegroups.com?subject=Help Needed%3A%20{{case.id}}{{case.subject}}
```

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: Which language/platform are u using?

Answer (score 0):

This would require the use of some sort of scripting language. The easiest way is to do this at the client side with a few lines of js.

I would do something like this in javascript:

```
// get the current url
var url = window.location.href;
// get the position of the last slash in the url
var lastSlash = url.lastIndexOf('/');
// get all the text that is after the last slash
var newUrl = url.substr(lastSlash + 1);
// set this as the new url
window.location.href = newUrl;
```

I put plenty of comments in the code, but feel free to ask...

It would be possible to do this in php or any other server side language as well, if that suits your needs better. Should not be to hard to find out there...